# Accessing a struct by index

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, struct

I'm being passed a pointer to a struct, and the first 8 members are the same size, can I access them by index?

```
 typedef struct example{
    uint64_t one;
    uint64_t two;
    uint64_t three;
    uint64_t four;
    uint64_t five;
    //etc...

    uint8_t ninth;

 } example_t;


void example_method(example_t *ptr)
{
    //can I do this?
    &ptr[2] // which would be equal to the uint64_t third?
}
```

Comment: It is fiddly and requires cheating that isn't guaranteed to work.  You'd be better off getting the structure redesigned, perhaps using an array only, or perhaps using a `union` of an array and the substructure (with some caveats about that, too).  It is best to design the structure to match the use patterns — if you're going to need to treat it as an array, store it as an array.

Comment: Agree with @JonathanLeffler in that you'd be better off redesigning the structure.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you cannot reliably take an struct member by index is that struct may contain arbitrary *padding* between members, as well as after last member. According to C11, N1570 §6.7.2.1/p15 *Structure and union specifiers*:

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

What you can do about it is to redefine your struct to contain array member (or possibly [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

Comment: Good answer---was not aware of the flexible array member. :) Even if there were no padding, how would you access a struct member using indexing?

Comment: @blazs: AFAIR, the only standard-compliant facility to access member in such way is to use `offsetof` macro. One reason for that is padding, the second one is that types could be of different size (and alignment requirements).

Comment: @blazs: As Grezegorz wrote: use an array member, don't even think about  something hacky. The names of the elements already imply some numerical indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The way the code looks with now you can't, but you can get away with is if you structure things differently:

```
typedef union example
{
   struct {
          uint64_t one;
          uint64_t two;
          uint64_t three;
          uint64_t four;
          uint64_t five;
          //etc...

          uint8_t ninth;

    };
    uint64_t array[9];
}example_t;
```

now you can do:

```
void example_method(example_t *ptr)
{        
    ptr->array[2]; // access fields by index
}
```

But, a word of warning: you can run into trouble because of compiler alignment defaults- for example, suppose you add one more field, which is a *char*, the compiler might try to align it to 4 bytes (some have this default) which will mess things up, especially if the field is somewhere i n the middle of your struct.

Comment: Note that you are accessing member `three` when you do `ptr->array[2]`.

Comment: @JonathanLefflerIf you're lucky, and there's no padding. The only certainty you have is that `ptr[0]` and `ptr->one` are the same

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: If you have a sequence of N elements of identical types at the start of a structure, then I know of no compiler that will add padding between the elements — assuming they're not bit-fields.  Padding appears when there are different types, and in particular when a type requiring stringent alignment follows a type requiring less stringent alignment in a structure.  The `ninth` element (`int8_t` rather than `int64_t`) probably has no padding before it; it probably will have padding after it. But yes, it is possible for a compiler to screw you.  In this, they usually don't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I completely agree with you. In this particular case, it's highly unlikely for a compiler to add padding bits. However, the OP did not post the entire struct, and the last element does have a different type. If, for example, the sixth and eighth members have different types, then a union won't work properly. It's best to avoid the grey areas that surround undefined behaviour whenever possible, that's why I commented. The only thing you _could_ do is use compiler features (like GCC's `__attribute__((__packed__))`) or do manual padding (architecture specific macro mess)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Saying `ptr[2]` is equivalent to `*(ptr+2)` which first adds `sizeof(struct example)` to the address `ptr`, and then dereferences.

Of course you can have an array in the struct instead of eight members:

```
struct example {
    uint64_t members[8];
    uint8_t ninth;
};
```

in which case you can access the third element of the array with `ptr->members[2]`. If the names of the members are not `one`, `two`, etc. you can defined an

```
enum Member_Names {
    FIRST_NAME = 0,
    SECOND_NAME = 1,
    ...,
    EIGTH_NAME = 7
};
```

and then use `ptr->members[THIRD_NAME]`.

Comment: So there is no way to access the struct by index of members?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Of course you can have an array in the struct instead of nine members: `struct example { uint64_t members[8]; uint8_t ninth; }` in which case you can access the second element of the array with `ptr->members[2]`.

Comment: I meant the third element, not the second element; sorry. :)